# Can I change the password of Backtrack running on a Live USB?

Tags: passwords, linux, usb-storage, backtrack

I am planning to run backtrack in Live USB mode with persistent memory, can I change the password of root, because my friends will certainly mess up with the files if it has default root/toot credentials.

Answer (score 4):

Run `passwd` while being root.

Follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just type `passwd` as root and change the password. Next time you log in you will have to use your new password.